# Flex : How to display a DataGrid selectedItem's details in a Form

Tags: apache-flex

Sorry for this long post. The question is however small but requires full detail. Thanks for reading and helping :)

I used HTTPService POST method to call a php file that returns me an xml type of result like

```
<user>
 <name>jones</name>
 <age>34</age>
</user>
```

This result is obtained after the php files queries a database. The database contain other information too like (height, gender, education and address)

Now i have a **DataGrid** (having two columns: NAME and AGE) and a **Form** below the DataGrid. I have displayed the above mentioned xml data in the DataGrid using the **dataprovider="{userRequest.lastResult.User}"** attribute.

I now want to use the **itemclick=itemClickEvent(event)** so that when a user click on a row of the DataGrid other information related to the clicked row like (height, gender, education etc) may appear in the form which is placed below the DataGrid in the GUI. For now my itemClickEvent,  look like:

```
private function itemClickEvent(event:ListEvent):void
{
  clickRow.text=String(event.rowIndex);
   //Don't know what should i assign to following labels...
   //height.text=
   //gender.text=
   //edu.text=
}
```

Form's structure:

*Is there any way i may access the xml data from the **itemClickEvent function**?* given that the DataGrid structure header look like

```
<mx:DataGrid id="dgUserRequest" dataProvider="{userRequest.lastResult.user}" x="28.7" y="36" width="525" height="149" itemClick="itemClickEvent(event);">
```

and the HTTPService header look like

```
<mx:HTTPService id="userRequest" url="request.php" method=POST">
     <mx:request xmlns="">
       <getResult>send</getResult>
     </mx:request>
</mx:HTTPService>
```

---

The concerned part of my php file is:

```
if($_POST['getResult'] == 'send')
{
   $Result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userInfo" );
   $Return = "<userInfo>";
   while ( $row = mysql_fetch_object( $Result ) )
   {
     $Return .= "<user><name>".$row->name."</name><age>".$row->age."</age><height>". $row->height."</height><gender>". $row->gender."</gender><education>".$row->education."</education></user>";
   }
   $Return .= "</userInfo>";
   mysql_free_result( $Result );
   print ($Return);
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `userRequest.lastResult.user.name` as the `dataProvider` for the data grid, what are your `dataField`s in the name and age columns?

There is another easy way to do this. Let's say the xml structure is something like:

```
<someRootTag>
 <user>
  <name>jones</name>
  <age>34</age>
  <height>180cm</height>
 </user>
 <user>
  <name>john</name>
  <age>4</age>
  <height>100cm</height>
 </user>
 <!--more <user/> tags-->
</someRootTag>
```

You can achieve this using data binding. Note that `resultFormat` of `HTTPService` has been changed to `e4x` from the default `object`

```
<mx:HTTPService id="service" url="data.xml" resultFormat="e4x"/>
<mx:DataGrid id="dg" dataProvider="{service.lastResult.user}">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="name"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="age"/>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
<mx:Form>
    <mx:FormItem label="Name">
        <mx:TextInput text="{dg.selectedItem.name}"/>
    </mx:FormItem>
    <mx:FormItem label="Age">
        <mx:TextInput text="{dg.selectedItem.age}"/>
    </mx:FormItem>
    <mx:FormItem label="Height">
        <mx:TextInput text="{dg.selectedItem.height}"/>
    </mx:FormItem>
</mx:Form>
```

The only AS code you need is to call `service.send()` from `creationComplete` of the application.

Comment: Sorry i mistyped that. I was using dataProvider=userRequest.lastResult.user and the columns' datafields were "name" and "age".

Anyway thanks for the solution but it's not working. (See my answer for details please)

Comment: This code is working, I tested it. It won't work if you change the resultFormat though. I'm not much into php, but that seems okay. What does it print?

Comment: You've to edit the httpservice to include the required post data.

Comment: Add `result=trace(service.lastResult);` to the HTTPService tag to see what exactly is being sent from php.

Comment: The php returns following string
"<userInfo><user><name>John</name><age>34</age><height>5.5</height><gender>male</gender><education>Phd Computer Science</education></user><user><name>Gessy</name><age>32</age><height>5.5</height><gender>female</gender><education>Phd Computer Science</education></user></userInfo>"

Comment: As its a string so it may need to be converted to xml first which i am figuring out as to how to do it.

Where exactly should i add **result=trace(service.lastResult);?

Comment: The resultFormat="e4x" handles converting from string to xml. See http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/rpc/http/HTTPService.html#resultFormat

Comment: Also note that the dataProvider of the DataGrid in our codes are different. I'm using `service.lastResult.user`

Comment: That's because my HTTPService id="userRequest" and you used id="service".

Thanks for the adobe live docs link. Its good that string to xml is catered automatically by e4x but it's really strange that the code is still not producing desired result.

Comment: what's happening now? is it being displayed in the datagrid at all?

Comment: Are you sure dataProvider="{service.lastResult.user}". Shouldn't it be
dataProvider="{service.lastResult.someRootTag.user}" ? given that we follow your version of xml document as you posted in your answer.

Comment: if resultFormat is e4x, lastResult.user is enough; if it is the default (object), we need lastResult.userInfo.user Copy my code into a new flex app and see it for yourself.

Comment: I tried with your xml and it's working. Make sure that resultFormat is e4x and dataProvider is service.lastResult.user Check the dataFields of columns and make sure there aren't any other errors/typos in the code

Comment: Can you please paste you mxml file on http://utilitybase.com/paste and give me its link?

Comment: No need Amarghosh. It's working now. A million thanks for your support and patience :)